# How can I store Maps in POJOs in Solr?

Tags: dictionary, solr, lucene, schema

How can I store Maps in POJOs in Solr? Currently I have a construct like this

```
@Field("*_locId")
protected Map<String, Integer> geoLocationToLocationId;
```

In the schema.xml file:

```
<dynamicField name="*_locId" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

adding via:

```
public void addGeoLocationToLocationAutoInMapping(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates,
        Integer id) {
    if(this.geoLocationToLocationId == null) {
        this.geoLocationToLocationId = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }
    this.geoLocationToLocationId.put(geoCoordinates.toString() +
            "_locId", id);
}
```

getting is similar.

This works, but it's kinda dirty that I store a Java Map like this in Solr because I can get loads of fields. Is there another way to write Java Maps into Solr?

I don't want to index them, I just want to save the data.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Depending on your use-case perhaps it would be better to store the map in another datastore (mongo, couchbase, redis, etc.) and do a quick lookup after you've retrieved results frrom Solr. Only keeping data in SOlr that you actually use for quering, and retrieving the rest through this 2-stop process is a common (dare I say best-practice) pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I would like to follow @Geert-Jan's advice in general, there are times you just want to have Solr return all the data you need. A better hack to store a simple map (String to Integer) like yours in Solr is to store the keys and values as two separate multi-valued fields and make sure the indexes agree on them. So you would have one mutli-valued field like:

geo_location: `new york, los angeles, chicago`

and another like

location_id: `1, 2, 3`

And make sure that none of the values is null in the `location_id` field, else your indexes in the fields won't match.

Comment: Hmm. I wasn't sure whether this is possible and therefore came up with my solution. Thx.

Comment: could it be that my approach also yields longer query times because of the big amount of fields (apart from the bigger traffic needed for transfering)?

Comment: The query time won't be increased since your fields are not indexed, but network time may be more. You need to benchmark both the cases and see.